# Comparing records if exist in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here I have html table displays records came from database. I tried to disable or void the delete button if value is already in both table1 and table2. I fetch another while loop inside of while loop to get the value from table2. But my problem is when I tried to run this, only 1 row/record is disabled or being void. It selects only the first record in the database. How I can store all of item_code in one variable? Any help please !

Just like the image below, ballpen and mimeo paper is already in table2, but ballpen delete button not been void.

[image]

```
$query1 = $mysqli1->query("select * from code WHERE item LIKE '%$search%' OR item_code LIKE '%$search%' OR cat_code LIKE '%$search%' order by item_code ASC");

while($r = $query1->fetch_assoc()){
echo"<tr>
    td>".$r['item']."</td>
    <td>".$r['cat_code']."</td>
    <td>".$r['item_code']."</td>";

result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT item_code FROM app order by id ASC");
        while($rows = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
            $ok = $rows['item_code'];
            }
        if($ok != $r['item_code']) {
            echo "<td><a href='#' id='".$r['id']."' class='del'><img src='../images/del.png'></a></td>";
        } else {
        echo "<td><a href='javascript:void(0)'><img src='../images/stop.png' border='0' width='10' height='10' title='Already Add in Purchase Request' style='cursor: not-allowed;'></a></td>";
        }
        echo"</tr>";
        }
```

Comment: can show your result?

Comment: you try to put if else statement inside while loop see what is the result

Comment: @user3462511 I also tried that, but the TD duplicate by loop

Comment: what the mean? can show the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with the following code

```
<?php
$query1 = $mysqli1->query("select * from code WHERE item LIKE '%$search%' OR item_code LIKE '%$search%' OR cat_code LIKE '%$search%' order by item_code ASC");
$ok = false;

while($r = $query1->fetch_assoc()){
    $ok = false;
    echo"<tr>
            <td>".$r['item']."</td>
            <td>".$r['cat_code']."</td>
            <td>".$r['item_code']."</td>";

        $result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT item_code FROM app order by id ASC");
        while($rows = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
            if($r['item_code'] == $rows['item_code']) {
                $ok = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!$ok) {
            echo "<td><a href='#' id='".$r['id']."' class='del'><img src='../images/del.png'></a></td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td><a href='javascript:void(0)'><img src='../images/stop.png' border='0' width='10' height='10' title='Already Add in Purchase Request' style='cursor: not-allowed;'></a></td>";
        }

        echo"</tr>";
}
```

What I did, was convert $ok to a flag variable (boolean), and each iteration of the main loop, I reset that variable to false (not found).  I also moved the field check inside the inner loop, and if a match was found, I set $ok = true  (match found), and exit the loop gracefully (break; ).

I will see if I can clean this code up a bit as looping through the database when you know the query is static ("SELECT foo FROM bar ORDER BY id ASC"), may be better handled by either pre-populating an ARRAY, or a simple  'IN ()' inside the SQL command would suffice.

### FOLLOWING IS A MORE ELEGANT WAY TO HANDLE THIS

Assuming both the 'app' and 'code' tables are in the same database.

```
$query1 = $mysqli1->query("SELECT
*,
(SELECT COUNT(app.item_code) FROM app WHERE app.item_code=code.item_code) as `mycheck`
FROM
code,
app
WHERE item LIKE '%$search%' OR item_code LIKE '%$search%' OR cat_code LIKE '%$search%' order by item_code ASC";

while($r = $query1->fetch_assoc()){
    echo"<tr>
            <td>".$r['item']."</td>
            <td>".$r['cat_code']."</td>
            <td>".$r['item_code']."</td>";

        if(intval($r['mycheck']) == 0) {
            echo "<td><a href='#' id='".$r['id']."' class='del'><img src='../images/del.png'></a></td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td><a href='javascript:void(0)'><img src='../images/stop.png' border='0' width='10' height='10' title='Already Add in Purchase Request' style='cursor: not-allowed;'></a></td>";
        }

        echo"</tr>";
}
```

In this example, I modified the original query to join the *COUNT* of the same result you are searching for inside the inner loop, as a field named 'mycheck`.  Then it is a simple matter to check if that field has an integer value greater than 0, if it does, it means that records exist in the other table. On very large databases, this may take slightly longer to execute, however overall it will be faster and save on connections to the database, with the total results being delivered all at once :)

Comment: $ok = false inside and outside of while loop?

Comment: Correct, outside is to initialize the variable. Inside the loop is to reset it on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: about your second answer. Each table has different database. So I can't use this and stick in your first answer

Comment: I gave a solution based on the code you supplied.  It would be up to you to adjust for all the different tables (if using more than  app, and code) tables.  But if you mean they are using completely separate databases (not just tables in the same DB), then the first solution will work for you.  The second solution I provided above is assuming both tables are in the same database.